# Nicescroll bar jump after resize

Tags: jquery, nicescroll

I m using nicescroll bar version 3.5.4..

*My code*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nicescroll").niceScroll({"autohidemode":false});   
    var test = $("#nicescroll").getNiceScroll();
    $("button").click(function() {
        test.resize();
    });
});
```

*My Issue*

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlVTt.png

After resize the scrollbar,scrollbar rail is move to somewhere..

Please help me to fix this issue...

Please scroll & click the button in jsfiddle

jsfiddle : http://fiddle.jshell.net/henry_robert/4JAE6/3/

**Update :**
Issue is in chrome & safari.In firefox its working fine

Comment: This also happens if you refresh the page after scrolling to somewhere in the middle of the `body`. I had to downgrade to [NiceScroll 3.5.0](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-nicescroll/downloads/detail?name=jquery.nicescroll.350beta5.7z) to fix it.

Comment: New version seems to fix, can you confirm?

Comment: i m using `jquery.nicescroll 3.5.4` !!